# ProgressRing In Uwp

Tags: c#, uwp, universal

my app is c# universal or Uwp . I Have 10 Pictures , I Want When Someone click on next button, before completely loaded picture in picture Box , Progress Ring Show To Client. And When its loaded, Progress Ring Disabled . how can I do that?

Comment: You can, there's a toolkit for that, but you need to add your code first, just so others can provide clear solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can put `Image` in `Grid` as below

```
<Grid>
  <ProgressRing IsActive="True"/>
  <Image Source="ms-appx:///Images/Image.png" Loaded="HideProgressRing"/>
</Grid>
```

and hide `ProgressRing` when `Loaded` event raised.

Comment: its not working. in  loaded event I put this---- >>>     Bilbilak.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

Comment: Yes, you have to add some logic to Loaded event

Comment: i know. but its not working. i add this on loaded event

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you could use [**XamlBehaviors**](https://github.com/microsoft/XamlBehaviors) to control the ProgressRing in xaml code, and please note image control will invoke [`ImageOpened`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.imageopened) event when the source load complete. For the detail please refer the following.

```
xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:Interactions="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"

 <Grid>
        <ProgressRing x:Name="Ring" IsActive="True"/>
        <Image Source="https://xxxxxxxx.com/full/38192.jpg">
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ImageOpened">
                    <Interactions:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=Ring}" PropertyName="IsActive" Value="False"/>
                </Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </Image>
 </Grid>
```